# Kafka: one producer for two topics vs. two producers

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

There are two kafka-topics:

- **logs** (in text format), for this case I use standard StringSerializer for Kafka
- **events** (in JSON format), for this case I use custom JSON Serializer for Kafka

There is some REST web-application (based on Servlet).
Which approach is best for this application?

**Approach 1**: Create single producer for both topics:

```
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, AnyRef](...props...)

// send logs
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, AnyRef](
       topic = "logs", "some log key", "some log str"))

// send events
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, AnyRef](
       topic = "events", "some evt key", Event("some"))
```

**Approach 2**: Create two producers with strong types of values.

```
val logsProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](...props...)
val eventsProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, Event](...props...)

// send logs
logsProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](
       topic = "logs", "some log key", "some log str"))

// send events
eventsProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, Event](
       topic = "events", "some evt key", Event("some event"))
```

---

**Update 1**: For the Approach-1 I use own serializer based on Json4s:

```
class KafkaJson4sSerializer[T <: AnyRef] extends Serializer[T] {

  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.native.Serialization
  import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write

  implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

  override def configure(configs: util.Map[String, _], isKey: Boolean): Unit = {}

  override def serialize(topic: String, data: T): Array[Byte] = {

    write(data).getBytes
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {}
}

val p = new Properties()
p.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
       "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
p.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
       "KafkaJson4sSerializer") // use the above own serializer
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, AnyRef](p)

// send string type to topic 'logs'
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, AnyRef]("logs", "k1", "string value"))
// send Event type to another topic 'events'
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, AnyRef]("events", "k2", Event("some evt")))
```

Comment: I would prefer strongly typed :), will you require producers specific properties ?

Comment: I don't get it. In the first case, how are you going to create a producer with two serializers at once?

Comment: @Dima I've added additional information (upd 1) about serializer for Approach-1. It works.